# WPF ListView with millions of rows

Tags: wpf, listview, large-data

I need to display a very large amount of data in a list view, up to 5 million or more rows. I am trying to find a solution where I can show all of the 5 million of items without having all of the 5 million items in my applications memory.

So basically the idea is that only a small amount of the items are shown, like 1k or 2k and when scrolling new data is retrieved from a database on demand. So that the application never has more then a couple of thousand item in its application memory. However the user should not realize that this is done, the listview should behave as if it had 5 million rows. Which means if he drags the scrollbar way down it should display the last of the 5 million rows and not the last of the couple of thousand rows that are currently in memory.

Does anyone of you have concept how such a feature can be achieved? I am grateful for any input you can provide.

Thanks,
m00ni

Comment: How do you expect user to go through 1k, let alone 5 million, rows to find something? Why can't you do some sort of pagination?

Comment: There are ways to filter the data to have less than 5 million items that match the criteria. There actually are very accurate filters. So it is not always a couple of millions, it could be only 50k or something, however even then our aim is to not have more then a couple of thousand objects in memory, if possible. With paging, do you mean the traditional page 1 to X that a user can go through and each page has a certain amount of items that are displayed? If so then yes we discussed it but apparently the usability guys didn't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data virtualization in wpf is much discussed - [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.UyhZMYVjLqc) is a good starting place.

I have implemented an approach that is somewhat different from anything I've found online. It isn't perfect but it suits my needs quite well.

I have a generic ItemsProvider interface that can page through data and exposes some other basic functions and info about the backing data. I also created a VirtualizationManager class that inherits from `DependencyObject` and has dependency properties `ScrollableHeight` and `VerticalOffset`. These are bound to the matching properties on a `ScrollViewer` (found in the templates of your finer `ItemsControls`). When either of these properties change they fire a callback that calculates how close the scroll viewer is to the end of the (currently loaded) list - for this my VirtualizationManager needs a handle to the ItemsProvider - and if that is less than some minimum amount the ItemsProvider is instructed to load the next page. The whole contraption can be installed on an `ItemsControl` via a set of attached properties.

My implementation is rather idiosyncratic, but the idea is fairly simple.

If you're dealing with very large lists you'll want a solution that not only loads incrementally but also unloads old items. There is at least one such solution at the link above.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This sounds like a very valid concept. I will try this out.

Comment: @mcwyrm: The link is not valid anymore. Could you please post it again?

Comment: @CarlosBomtempo Maybe, you want this link [WPF: Data Virtualization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)